# Web page with two tabs.Tranfer one item to another tab

Tags: angularjs, tabs

I need to do app,which doing something like that:
One web page separated on 2 tabs.
In first tab we have list of items. If you click on item it should be transferred to another tab and should be hidden on first tab.
Tools to do this thing is AngularJS.
Any ideas about that? Sorry for this question. I'm noobie in AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really basic example of how you could implement your idea with AngularJS:

**Tabs**

one easy way to create tabs is to create the markup and use your controller to hold a reference to which tab to show:

```
// in the controller 
$scope.currentTab = 1; 

// in the markup
<li class="tab" ng-show="currentTab === 1">
  ... tab contents
</li>
... repeat for as many tabs as you want
```

you could then change the tab inside an `ng-click` directive in your page markup:

```
// in the markup
<a ng-click="currentTab = 1">change to tab 1</a>
```

**Items**

to show items in your tab first create the items in your controller:

```
// in the controller
$scope.tab1Items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

then display in your tab:

```
// in the markup
<li class="tab">
  <div ng-repeat="item in tab1Items">{{ item }}</div>
  ... 
</li>
```

**Moving the items**

This can be done with a function in `ng-click` that passes the item from one array of items to another:

```
// in the controller
$scope.moveItem = function(item) {
  if ($scope.tab1Items.indexOf(item) > -1) {
    $scope.tab1Items.splice($scope.tab1Items.indexOf(item), 1);
    $scope.tab2Items.push(item);
  }
  else {
    $scope.tab2Items.splice($scope.tab2Items.indexOf(item), 1);
    $scope.tab1Items.push(item);
  }
}

// in the markup
<div ng-repeat="item in tab1items" ng-click="moveItem(item)">
...
```

The concept here is to create a page with one controller that maintains current tab state, as well as the items to display in those tabs.  Since you have access to all the items in the same scope it's easy to manipulate and pass those items from one tab to another.

Here's a link to a basic working example in plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/PjSXI0JH4uQ1OW8u3f2z?p=preview

Comment: God bless, you paul trone, for helping beginners. :)